# Падает приложение

Tags: java, android

Ребята, не могу понять, почему падает приложение, помогите разобраться
В задумке: оно должно выполнять два разных сценария в зависимости от того, наступило или нет определенное время.
Код:
MainActivity

```
    package ru.abrakadabra.timecat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    {
        int x = 1541394736; // задано конкретное время в UNIX
        if (x < System.currentTimeMillis()/10) { // вызываем системное время, делим его на 10 для получения UNIX
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем первый сценарий
            /* todo */
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем второй сценарий
            /* todo */
        }
    }
}
```

Activity1

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
    }
}
```

Activity2

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
    }
}
```

activity_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Это окно запустится, если СЦЕНАРИЙ 1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Это окно запустится, если СЦЕНАРИЙ 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.abrakadabra.timecat">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" />
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса полный stack trace возникающей ошибки.

Comment: это я тут ошибся, когда копировал код, активити 2 существует, поправил код выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package ru.abrakadabra.timecat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
```

в этом **отдельном** блоке кода нет контекста - поскольку выполняется до его инициализации (считай в конструкторе) и поэтому `startActivity` не может быть выполнен.
Если Вам нужно чтобы этот код выполнился при запуске активности то уберите фигурные скобки до и после этого текста

```
    {  
        int x = 1541394736; // задано конкретное время в UNIX
        if (x < System.currentTimeMillis()/10) { // вызываем системное время, делим его на 10 для получения UNIX
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем первый сценарий
            /* todo */
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent); // реализуем второй сценарий
            /* todo */
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Unix Epoch считает время в целых секундах, а `System.currentTimeMillis()` возвращает время в **милли**-секундах - это `1/1000`, а не `1/10`.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы попали в точку! Только почему то ставлю x дату 05.11.2018, 13:12:16, а запускается сценарий 2

Comment: UPD: запутался со знаками "больше", "меньше"! Все норм. Ваше решение полностью правильное!